# Can't Update Sharepoint Linked List With Access

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

I just linked my Access db to a list in sharepoint. Now i'm trying to run an append query, but i always get the error: "object cannot be updated because it is read only".

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you work in Microsoft Access, you run update queries against a linked Microsoft SharePoint view. The underlying list that you are updating includes lookup fields that are not linked to Access because they are not included in the current view.

You could try the two methods:

1.Link all the lookup columns in the underlying list to tables to make them writable.

2.Disable caching in Access 2010.

For more information, you could refer to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/error-query-against-linked-sharepoint-view